# How to write an equation which mapping a square into a sphere?

Tags: math-software, stereographic-projections

Let say the curved cells on that sphere actually create a perfect square grid in shadow.

[image]

Is it possible to write an equation which will mapping the square in 2D into the curved cell in 3D?

The square's equation in 2D is
|x| + |y| = a.

Comment: The mapping from a point on the sphere to the plane is the point that is on the plane and the line defined by the center of the sphere and the point on the sphere?

Comment: see [stereographic pojection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#First_formulation) on wiki.

Comment: @RushabhMehta, unfortunately, I don't understand the second part of your question. What means "the line defined by the center of the sphere and the point on the sphere?"

Comment: Would stereographic projection help?